# VBScript error 800A01B6 document.parentwindow.screen.availwidth

Tags: vbscript, runtime-error

[See Error Message here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ay6Lq.png)

I have a script that had been working fine since years. Last week, we changed the user account and suddenly it stopped working and started returning with VBScript error 800A01B6 document.parentwindow.screen.availwidth. If we login with the previous account and execute the script, it runs perfect as ever. However, it does not run with the new account. The new user account is also in the same Administrators group as the old account. I can't figure out the difference between the two executions.

Please help.

Here's a sample of the code:

```
Dim oIEPW, sPWHTML, ctr
Dim objWMIService, colItems, objItem, ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight, Scr
'Get HTML and place it in a variable
Call WriteHTML(sPWHTML)
'Create Internet Explorer object
'Set oIEPW = WScript.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application", "IE_")
Set oIEPW = WScript.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application", "IE_")
'Set window properties
With oIEPW
    .Navigate "about:blank" 'Use blank page as base
    Do While .ReadyState <> 4 'Wait for IE process to start
        WScript.Sleep 50
    Loop
    .Document.Open 'Create document that will be in IE window
    .Document.Write (sPWHTML) 'Paste in HTML
    .Document.Close 'Complete the page creation
    .Resizable = 0
    .ToolBar = 0 'Disable IE's tool bars
    .StatusBar = 0 'Disable IE's status bar
    .Width = 294 'Set window width in pixels
    .Height = 155 'Set window height in pixels
    ScreenWidth = .Document.ParentWindow.Screen.AvailWidth 'Find screen width in pixels
    .Left = (ScreenWidth / 2) - (.Width / 2) 'Distance in pixels of window left edge to left side of screen
    ScreenHeight = .Document.ParentWindow.Screen.AvailHeight 'Find screen height in pixels
    .Top = (ScreenHeight /2) - (.Height / 2) 'Distance in pixels of window top edge to top of screen
    'WshShell.Popup "Width: " & ScreenWidth & VbCrLf & "Height: " & ScreenHeight,,"Screen Resolution",4096
    Do While .ReadyState <> 4 'Wait for all properties to be set
        WScript.Sleep 50
    Loop
    .Visible = 1 'Make IE window visible
End With
'Bring IE window to the top
WshShell.AppActivate "Internet Explorer"
```

Comment: For help with your code: show your code (or rather a [mcve] of it). Show the complete error message. Explain how you're running the code.

Comment: I've submitted sample code for your reference as requested.

Comment: Try changing the code to all lowercase (`.document.parentwindow.screen.availwidth`).  See [this question](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28418004/VB-Script-error.html) on Experts-Exchange.